# Instantiating prefabs from another script (The prefab you want to instantiate is null)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null, instance

So I have an enemy spawner with a method to instantiate prefabs working just fine. Simplified:

```
public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject EnemyPrefab;

public void setEnemies()
{
    Instantiate (EnemyPrefab, enemyPos, rotation);
}

void Start()
{
    setEnemies();
}

}
```

This works fine. But it doesnt work when I call it from a different script:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
public EnemySpawner enemyspawner;

void Update(){
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
   {
      enemyspawner= new EnemySpawner();
       enemyspawner.setEnemies();
   }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> ArgumentException: The prefab you want to instantiate is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
So I figured that I could not create a Monobeaviour by using the New keyword .I changed it to:

```
enemyspawner = gameObject.AddComponent<EnemySpawner> ();

enemyspawner.setEnemies();
```

But that still wont work.

Comment: So I figured that I could not create a Monobeaviour by using the New keyword .I changed it to:  `code` enemyspawner = gameObject.AddComponent<EnemySpawner> ();

enemyspawner.setEnemies();

Answer (score 1):

I just read your comment about changing:

`new` to `enemyspawner = gameObject.AddComponent<EnemySpawner>();`

However, you did not properly solve the problem, you only made a workaround that won't work because your prefab, `public GameObject EnemyPrefab;`, won't be set.

With your new code `gameObject.AddComponent<EnemySpawner>();` You are attaching a script to the Player GameObject, this will bring you problems in the future.

---

#### My Suggestion

Create an Empty GameObject and attach `EnemySpawner` to it and name it **EnemySpawnerObj**.

Then to call the function `setEnemies()` from another class you do this:

```
EnemySpawner spwner = GameObject.Find("EnemySpawnerObject").GetComponent<EnemySpawner>();
spwner.setEnemies();
```

So what you are doing is looking through your scene for the GameObject named **EnemySpawnerObject** then you get the component named **EnemySpawner** and then you can call that class instance.